# .htaccess Rewrite modification

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We're currently using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^testsub/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testsub/$1 [L]
```

But, we're unable to to easily have more rules to rewrite subdomains to seperate folders.

Copying and pasting means all subdomains are going to testsub.website.com

If I add the following condition I can get around it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(test|alt)\.website\.com$ [NC]
```

But as you can see from below it's still a big, ugly rewrite... how can I easily make just 1 set of rules to do all of the below as like 4-5 lines max

```
RewriteRule ^testsub/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(test|alt)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testsub/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^test/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(testsub|alt)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^alt/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(testsub|test)\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ alt/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(testsub|test|alt)(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Gah, I wish I was good at these htaccess rules. That works perfectly. Thank you! Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks, too. I search on StackOverflow date by date, now I join this community to contribute my knowledge. :)

Comment: Your knowledge is much appreciated, I spent hours trying to work out how to do that myself as I really don't understand the rewrite rules.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I am new to this community. Thank you for letting me know.